# How to set -webkit-overflow-scrolling style from java script?

Tags: jquery, html, css, cordova, phonegap

I have to set -webkit-overflow-scrolling using java script
I tried with following code but not working

```
$("#myDiv").css("-webkit-overflow-scrolling","none");
```

On "myDiv" I have applied .scrollable class as follows

```
.scrollable{
             overflow-y: scroll;
             -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
           }
```

Comment: Do you want to set it to `touch` or `none` using script..? your code doesn't seem to have any syntax errors. the problem must be something else.. are you sure the div has an id `myDiv`, you've linked query, your script runs after it's created.. etc..?

Comment: I have to set none to -webkit-overflow-scrolling
- Yes, it has myDiv id
- I have linked jQuery
- my script runs after it created

I have tested in debugging mode by changing -webkit-overflow-scrolling value "touch" to "none", there its working fine
But as of I trying to runs by javascript, its not working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Any way to apply 'webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch' inline with javascipt?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11214554/any-way-to-apply-webkit-overflow-scrolling-touch-inline-with-javascipt)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the webkit-overflow-scrolling property with javascript like this:

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").style.webkitOverflowScrolling = "auto";
```

edit: none is not a valid value I think, that is why it isn't working. I think "auto" is what you want.

According to documentation you have these option available: https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/StandardCSSProperties.html

> auto: One finger scrolling without momentum.
>
> touch: Native-style
> scrolling. Specifying this style has the effect of creating a stacking
> context (like opacity, masks, and transforms)

Comment: There is no any property like webkitOverflowScrolling of any html element so its not working

Comment: I'm not calling it on an element, but on the element.style. so  element.<b>style<b>.webkitOverflowScrolling, it is there on Safari

Answer (score 0):

Can you just create a class instead, like a tool..?

I have this for use on my site when the content width is less than 700px

```
.tool-device-touch {
  @media (max-width: 700px) {
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    overflow-y: scroll;
  }
}
```

You could then just do this

```
$("#myDiv").addClass('tool-device-touch');
```

Wow asked nearly 4 years ago... :-D