# How to set -webkit-overflow-scrolling inline style on react component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am using inline style for react component. They can be defined as below.

```
const style= {
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: '7.5%',
    top: '5.2rem',
    overflowY: 'auto',
  },
```

It has some gramma different with css, like 'overflow-y' in css should be set as overflowY in inline style. Now I wander how to set this style -webkit-overflow-scrolling as inline style in react? I have tried below settings but none of them work.

```
WebkitOverflowScrolling: 'touch',
'-webkit-overflow-scrolling': 'touch',
```

Comment: What about `webkitOverflowScrolling`? (note lower case *w*)

Comment: "Multi word" properties (e.g. `font-size` etc.) are written in camelCase (as in `fontSize`).

Comment: As a recommendation if you're going to do a lot of styling with react, I would say to regular stylesheet files instead of setting style in react. The styling in JS just isn't there yet, you'll have a hard time debugging reused styles, you can't easily copy-paste css syntax, media queries are handled in JS instead of browser's css engine and so on. I had to use this on a project I joined and it was a bad developer experience overall.

Comment: I have tried to separate css from react component but it turn out that it is really hard to find a dom style. If we put styles in each component, it would be really easy to navigate between  dom and style. It is true that reuse styles are hard in this case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Any way to apply 'webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch' inline with javascipt?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11214554/any-way-to-apply-webkit-overflow-scrolling-touch-inline-with-javascipt)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've used this successfully:

```
overflowScrolling: "touch",
WebkitOverflowScrolling: "touch",
```